# Count number of unbroken 'strings' of numbers across a row in VBA Function

Tags: vba, excel, range, offset

I have been battling this one for days, and am clearly missing something. It has been a while since I last used VBA and I am struggling to remember.

Looking to find the number of 'tours' or uninterupted 'strings' of 1's across a row.

Data and answer I am looking for is this (with each number being in its own column):

```
0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 = 3
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 = 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 = 1
```

Have tried the following Functions:

```
Function TOURCOUNT(TourList As Range)
Dim var As Variant

var = TourList.Value

For Each var In TourList
    If var = 1 And var + 1 = 1 Then
    TOURCOUNT = TOURCOUNT
    ElseIf var = 1 Then
    TOURCOUNT = TOURCOUNT + 1
    End If
Next

End Function
```

And just running through the cells:

```
Function NTOURS(TList As Range)

Dim var As Variant

For Each Cell In TList
    If Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1 And Cell.Value = 1 Then
        NTOURS = NTOURS + 1
    End If
Next
End Function
```

And a few other minor variations. Clearly I am not understanind something correctly. The 'And' evaluate Offset if statement returned the wrong numbers when I accidently offset rows instead of columns. But when I correct that it just returns 0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but judging from your examples, something like this would do the work.

In general, you pass the range as a parameter, it goes in the row and it makes two checks pro case in the loop. If both checks are successful, `lngResult` is incremented.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Uninterrupted(rngRange As Range) As Long

    Dim rngCell         As Range
    Dim lngResult       As Long
    Dim blnInterruped   As Boolean

    For Each rngCell In rngRange
        If rngCell Then
            If Not blnInterruped Then lngResult = lngResult + 1
            blnInterruped = True
        Else
            blnInterruped = False
        End If
    Next rngCell

    Uninterrupted = lngResult

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I need!

Comment: Since you've passed in the whole range being checked, you don't need to make the function volatile.